# Can I disown a question or answer?

Tags: support, questions

I just got a scolding comment on [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing?noredirect=1#comment81329203_218760), saying that answers don't belong in questions.

While I fully agree, I committed this particular indiscretion nine years ago. It was made a community wiki 5 years ago and closed as a duplicate three years ago.

**I'm no longer interested in maintaining this question or its answers**. Can I disown it somehow, so that I'm no longer notified of comments, edits, etc.?

I understand that Stack Overflow wants things to be maintained forever, and that this is good for users who stumble on it. And for many of my posts, I do update them from time to time. But in this case, I want to move on.

**Can I disown a question or answer?**

Comment: I also sometimes get comments like "have you tried X?" or "what happens when you do Y?" on old questions. I'm like, "uh, I don't have this problem or any of the context anymore, and I... don't know that programming language anymore." 

Comment: Make your answers an answer and then make it a community answer, rather than trying to break StackOverflow by putting answers in the question.

Comment: @NathanLong: Note that if you use disassociation, then your name will no longer appear on it, all reputation from it is removed, and nobody can reach your profile through it. However, if you commented on it, you can still be ping-ed through `@` notifications (and I believe this is still true if you delete your comments). So this is not necessarily a tool to get people to stop bothering you for old questions/answers.

Comment: @NathanLong How about you pass the question to me, I'll be happy to take the REP. :) :) :) :D